# How to make a automatic dot connector in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr

I am trying to make a python application that automatically connects the dots in a connect-the-dot game. (https://ibb.co/pvfC8JC) - the application would connect dot 1 to dot 2 to dot 3, etc.. until the entire picture is complete. However, I am having a lot of issues with the recognition of the dots and numbers.

My approach is to locate the numbers and the dots in the image, associate each dot to a number, and then connect the dots.

I tried using pytesseract but it had significant issues in recognizing numbers and differentiating dots and numbers.

Which approach should I take in solving this problem?

I used the following code:

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('data/2.png')
ih, iw, _ = img.shape

data = pytesseract.image_to_data(
    img,
    output_type=Output.DICT,
)

print(data)
n = len(data['level'])

for i in range(n):
    x, y, w, h = (
        data['left'][i],
        data['top'][i],
        data['width'][i],
        data['height'][i],
    )
    cv2.rectangle(
        img,
        (x, y, w, h),
        (0, 255, 0),
        2,
    )

cv2.imwrite('ass.png', img)
```

which had the following result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj1xG.png)